# Create a timestamp given date values columns in Excel

Tags: excel, macos, date, timestamp

I have a date in the following format:

```
Column A: Day (number form)
Column B: Month (number form)
Column C: Year (yy number form, in my case just 15 and 16 for 2015 and 2016)
Column D: Hour (number form, 0 through 23)
Column E: Minute (number form)
```

How can I convert this into a timestamp (namely, a timestamp representing number of minutes)? I don't see any kind of "dateserial" type function in Excel (at least on my Mac version).

Comment: Is the date() function good enough, or do you need the hour and minute included?

Comment: hour and minute included -- I need a way to be able to tell how many minutes apart any two given rows are, so I just need some kind of timestamp but I don't know what the best way is to parse it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with this formula:

```
=DATE(2000+C1,B1,A1)+TIME(D1,E1,0)
```

This will get you a number around 42000, you will need to format it in the number format you want.

[image]

Then if you want to time difference between two rows you would simply use:

```
=F2-F1
```

And format the cell with a custom format of `[hh]:mm:ss`

[image]

**Note** the method that excel stores date/time is:

Dates are whole numbers for each day since Jan 1st 1900 so we are currently in the 42000's.

Time is a decimal based on 24 hours being 1.

So both together my current time is `42531.63956` or `6/10/2015 3:21:33` or so, when the mask is applied.

Excel uses this method so we can do math on the values.  The method on how the output is displayed depends on the format of the cell in which the number resides.

Comment: How can I convert this to number of minutes? This seems to yield a decimal? Remove time part, add 60*D1 + E1? Is that valid?

Comment: Like I said you need to format the output through the cell format into the date structure you want.

Comment: I have no context for what date() is returning. Seconds? Minutes? Something else?

Comment: It is returning a number like 42305.76849 which is how excel stores a date time.  Then you put a mask on it to look like a date through the cell format.  like the picture above. This allows the value to stay as a number but look like a date so you then can do math on the numbers. @user6419910

Comment: you say you want the number of minutes but you have one value.  do you want the number of minutes that day till that time or of that month or that hour, you need to give more reference. @user6419910

Comment: @findwindow I've been trying for over an hour, man. Excel does not make this stuff easy

Comment: @ScottCraner I mentioned up above in a separate comment chain, but I need some kind of minute timestamp so I can compare any two values and see how many minutes elapsed between them. Time since 1970 or whatever the Unix timestamp is should be fine too, whatever works

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
=DATE(CONCATENATE("20",C1),B1,A1) +  TIME(D1,E1,0)
```

Comment: Number of minutes?